# Creating a HTML page using PHP

Tags: php

Im building a small browser based canvas game. Im fine with Javascript and jquery but i have only mediocre experience with PHP and especially creating Webpages based on PHP.

What im currently doing is checking `$_GET` to retrieve some database data.
Depending on that data, i would like to create "unique" HTML pages.

For example: I have a page called `createGame.php` which checks if a Player is in a game.

If he is, i want to populate and display a table.

my php:

```
  <?php
    $gamedata = someObject // basicly the entire gamedata, playerIds, subObjects, a bunch of database data clumped together.

    if ($gamedata ->playerHasJoined()){
       $table = // code here to create a unique table element
    }
  ?>

  <body>
    <div>
      <?php echo $table ?>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Now, basically my question is: How do i "best" build up the table element ?
Do i do:

```
$table = "<table>";
$table .= "<tr><th>Im the Header</th></tr>";
$table .= "do this 50 times more";
```

Or is there a better way to create an element based on my `$gamedata` variable ?
Or should i use another way entirely to construct my HTML page ?

thank you

Comment: Might be useful to tell us what is in `$gamedata` so we have some idea of the data you are processing

Comment: Take a look at those answers http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159529/how-to-structure-template-system-using-plain-php

Comment: Your question is rather broad and probably opinion-based. However, and for my *"2 cents"*; you could use includes for the HTML markup and just use variables to be inserted where they're supposed to show up. Yet your *"do this 50 times more"* is unclear as to what that is supposed to hold. You could use a `foreach` for that, probably and if that is supposed to hold the db column(s) data.

Comment: For the opening table tag and header row, that's fine. Once you actually build the data rows, you could use a `while` or `foreach` to echo one tr.../tr per element of $gamedate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it seems like you want to create all the html right at the beginning and then just print the whole page. What I would do instead is to build all the boilerplate (the code that stays the same no matter what's in the response) and then echo stuff out throughout the page.

Example:

```
<body>
    <?php 
        $array = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php 
            foreach($array as $item) {
                echo "<li>" . $item . "</li>";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</body>
```

If you're doing something more complex i would advise you to use a template-engine like Twig (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to make life easier for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like it

```
    <table>
     <tr>
        <?php
        $header = array_keys($_GET);
        for ( $x=0; $x<count($header); $x++) {
        ?>

        <th><?=$header[$x]?></th>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the best way is to use a template engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Here is how it is done with Twig:

```php
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));

$rows = fetch_an_array_from_database();

echo $twig->render('index.html', [ 'table_rows' => $rows ]);
```

where `'/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'` is a file generated by [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

`index.html`:

```
<table>
{% for row in table_rows %}
<tr>
  <td>Name</td><td>{{ row.name }}</td>
  <td>Age</td><td>{{ row.age }}</td>
  <!-- etc. -->
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```